# GSL integration fail

Tags: c, gsl

I have a program that integrates a system of ordinary differential equations of the form:

```
dp0/dt = a - (1+gamma) * p0
dp1/dt = p0 - (1+gamma) * p1
dp2/dt = p1 - (1+gamma) * p2
dp3/dt = p2 - (1+gamma) * p3
```

I use `gsl_odeiv_evolve_apply` as an integration engine in the usual way:

```
while ((*t) < t1)
{      
    status = gsl_odeiv_evolve_apply(e, c, s, &sys, t, t1, &h, y);
    if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("\n ************ status: %d\n", status);
        break; 
    }
}
```

The `while` loop fails with `status = 32526` error code. I have printed the values of `p[i]` and `dp[i]/dt` step by step, and there are no NAN nor inf.

How can I know what causes this error?

Comment: When I use:
 printf ("error: %s\n", gsl_strerror (State)); I obtain:
error: unknown error code

Comment: Please provide a  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As far as I can tell, 32526 is indeed _not_ a valid GSL error code. Have you run your code with ASAN or valgrind to check that there's no memory corruption occurring?